# Class App\Http\Controllers\AdminController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

i have this error when user return from login to home page i can't understand what is it i am doing MultiAuth in laravel 5 and also help me if i can use login function and other registration function that is already available for users table i have no idea how to do that with already written functions

this is my login function

```
public function login()
    {
        $data = Input::all();

        // Applying validation rules.
        $rules = array(
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        );

        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()){
            // If validation falis redirect back to login.
            return Redirect::to('admin/login')->withInput(Input::except('password'))->withErrors($validator);
        }
        else {
            $userdata = array(
                'email' => Input::get('email'),
                'password' => Input::get('password')
            );
        }

        // doing login.
        if (Auth::validate($userdata)) {
            if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
                return Redirect::intended('admin');
            }
        }
        else {
            // if any error send back with message.
            Session::flash('error', 'Something went wrong');
            return Redirect::to('admin/login');
        }
    }
```

this is my AdminController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
//    public function __construct(){
//
//        $this->middleware('admins');
//    }
    public function index(){
//        $user = Auth::user();
//        dd($user);
        return view('admin.home');
    }
}
```

Comment: i am doing this for Admin

Comment: Class App\Http\Controllers\AdminController does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your controller:

```
protected $guard = 'admin';

public function login()
{
    $data = Input::only(['email', 'password']);

    // Applying validation rules.
    $rules = array(
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()){
        // If validation falis redirect back to login.
        return Redirect::to('admin/login')
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'))
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }

    if (Auth::->attempt($userdata)) {
        return Redirect::intended('admin');
    }
    return Redirect::to('admin/login')
        ->with('error', 'Something went wrong');
}
```

Comment: another problem with this function is that it match email and password with users table not admins table

Comment: i have two table users (already there) and admins and this form should validate email and password with admins table not users table

Comment: in if condition admin is my table name or model name?

Comment: admin is your connection name from config: `'admin' => array(`

Comment: i am using admins as connection name but it says method not found

Comment: can i miss any namespace?

Comment: please paste the config file

Comment: which bundle do you use for MultiAuth ?

Comment: when i am trying to login this error comes now ( call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard' does not have a method 'admins' )

Comment: i am not using any bundle please suggest any if its better to use it

Comment: :) are you serious... so what documentation you read? You have no idea about what you want to recive and you're talking about some MultiAuth ?!?!

Comment: Of corse that you will get this error if you dosen't have a MultiAuth bundle - Laravel dosen''t supports multi auth...

Comment: i read about it on internet and i see nothing about any bundle.... i am new in laravel that is why i have not as mush idea bout it

Comment: so what is the best way to do that

Comment: You need to find one. And depand on which version you're working on... You can try for example this one: https://github.com/Kbwebs/MultiAuth, but read doc first carefully

Comment: i am using laravel 5.2

Comment: I've found the solution for you. Add thios to controller: `protected $guard = 'admin';` and drop the `admin` method that I suggest you before.

Comment: So I'm affraid I can't help ypu more... I don't know this functionality so good

Comment: well probably it dosen't make sens if there is a solution like changing the guard config

Comment: can you send me any link about it

Comment: Last try with this: `Auth::guard('admin')->attempt`

Answer (score 6):

Problem is in your namespace. In the Contrroller you have:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
```

So the full name is:

```
App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController;
```

and the error you get is:

```
App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
```

You have to remove `Admin` from the ending of a namespace.

Comment: what i write in route?

Comment: Here: `Route::get('admin', 'Admin\AdminController@index');`

Comment: AdminController is not in Admin folder it is in Controller folder

Comment: OK. So you have to remove `Admin` from namespace!

Comment: i add it but now the error is something like this Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController does not exist

Comment: namespace App\Http\Controllers;

Comment: yes.... also remove the thing from route and live like before: `Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index');`

Comment: thanks this work for me but i have another issue can you solve it for me?? please...

Comment: Sure... make another issue here I will check it immidietly

Comment: Ok can you create a new Question on StackOverflow and write there everything?

Comment: you see i write a login function for my admin but i want to use built in authentication that is for users table

Comment: ok i put a new question there in 2 minutes please help me to solve it there

Comment: it could not allow me to post another question before 90 minutes

Comment: Ok I will write here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112773/discussion-between-muhammad-arslan-and-filip-koblanski).

Answer (score 5):

As of Laravel 8, you need to define your routes like this 
`Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index']);` 
 Instead of this 
`Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');`

Answer (score 0):

my route file is

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //Login Routes...
    Route::get('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@login');
    Route::get('/admin/logout','AdminAuth\AuthController@logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    Route::get('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@register');

    Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my config/auth.php file

```
<?php

return [


    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],



    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],


    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: Ok this is bit different. So in your controller class just add: `protected $guard = 'admin';`

Answer (score 0):

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

Comment: this might be the class header, but how does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

There may be many different reasons for this error. But I experienced such error and the problem was that I did not include the ".php" in the filename. Thus, I changed the "AdminController" to "AdminController.php" and the problem solved. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

in laravel 9 you must be check at \App\Http\Kernel.php

in a middleware you should be add
'admin' => Admin::class
and dont forget on top import this
use App\Http\Middleware\Admin;

if you edit the function middleware admin.php

Answer (score 0):

adding these two lines solved my problem..

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; ---->Dont forget to add this line